# Why $\overline{\operatorname{Mov}(X)}\subset \overline{\operatorname{Eff}(X)}$, where $X$ is any normal variety?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry

I am trying to understand why $\overline{\operatorname{Mov}(X)}\subset \overline{\operatorname{Eff}(X)}$, where $X$ is any normal variety.

Here $\operatorname{Mov}(X)$ is the convex cone generated by movable divisors in $N^1(X)$, and $\operatorname{Eff}(X)$ is the cone generated by effective divisors on $X$. A divisor is movable if $\operatorname{Codim}(B(D))\geq 2,$ where
$$B(D)=\cap_{m\geq 1}Bs(|mD|).$$
So essentially, I am trying to prove that any movable divisor is a limit of effective divisors. But I do not have any alternate description of movable divisors, which is making the task more difficult and non-intuitive.

Comment: If the linear system of a Cartier divisor class is empty, then the base locus equals the entire ambient scheme by definition / convention.  So your hypothesis on the base locus of some positive integer multiple of the Cartier divisor class implies that multiple is effective.  Therefore the closure of the $\mathbb{Q}_{\geq 0}$-cone generated by movable divisors is contained in the closure of the $\mathbb{Q}_{\geq 0}$-cone generated by effective divisors.

Comment: We know that there exists $m_0>>0$, such that $B(D)=Bs(|m_0D|)$ (Prop. 2.1.21, [Positivity I, Lazarsfeld]). Hence $\operatorname{Codim}(Bs(|m_0D|))\geq 2,$ this means that $|m_0D|\neq \phi$, which proves that $m_0D$ and thus $D$ is effective.

Comment: Unrelated: "\empytset" will give you $\emptyset$ and "\gg" will give you $\gg$, similarly "\ll" for $\ll$.